# バフェットコードのWebAPIをcurlから使いたいです

Tags: api, curl

以下のバフェットコードのWebAPIをcurlから使いたいです。

http://docs.buffett-code.com/

どのように叩けばレスポンスが得られますか。

Comment: 2件の質問しか存在しない特定サイトのためにタグを作成するべきではないと思われ、編集をロールバックしました。

Answer (score 1):

API Keyでの認証を行っているため以下のように`x-api-key`ヘッダーにAPI Keyを設定してください。

```
$ curl -s https://api.buffett-code.com/api/v2/indicator\?tickers\=2120\&from\=2017Q1\&to\=2018Q1 \
    --header 'x-api-key: <Your API Key>'
```

API Keyが正しければJSON形式のレスポンスが返ります。